# Find the count of new accounts in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an account and a date dimension table. I have joined these two tables on the basis of account_creation_date. I have a requirement to find the count of new accounts, and I have used logic like

```
case 
    when date(account_creation_date) = current_date() 
        then 1 
        else 0 
end
```

This returns the exact same count as count of accounts. I know that's happening just because I have joined these two table on the basis of `account_creation_date`. Could you please tell me how I can tweak the SQL to make these two measures different? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is not valid in SQL Server and would return an error.

Comment: `THEN 1 ELSE 0` is always count to return a non-`NULL` value, and so every row will be counted. You either want to get the `SUM` of that `CASE` expression *or* use `COUNT` and omit the `ELSE`. The `SUM` of the values 1,0,0,0,1,1 is `3`, but the `COUNT` is `6`. On the other hand, both the `SUM` and `COUNT` of 1,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,1 is `3`.

Comment: Great comment @Larnu. This should be in its own post somewhere. Good general knowledge for new SQL users.